# Angular 6: what is the Reflect API in polyfills.ts?

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer, cross-browser, polyfills

In `polyfills.ts`, one of the commented out lines reads as follows:

```
/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
// import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
```

What is the 'Reflect API'? What IE use cases is it needed for and is this import statement typically important when running an `Angular` application in `IE`? Surprisingly, Google and StackOverflow didn't turn up many/any results for me.

Comment: Polyfills are used to provide backwards compatibility in older browsers that have not yet implemented some of the newer features. In this case, that functionality is [the `Reflect` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ES6 Reflect API gives you a Reflect object that lets you call methods, construct objects, getting and setting prototypes, manipulating and extending properties.
Reflect is a built-in object that provides methods for interceptable JavaScript operations. The methods are the same as those of proxy handlers. More details, please check the [Reflect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect) and the [ES6 Reflect API Tutorial](http://qnimate.com/es6-reflect-api-tutorial/)

From the [Browser compatibilitySection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect#Browser_compatibility), we can see IE not support Reflect, by using the Polyfills, it makes us using Reflect in IE browser.